# TCL Comparisons by Proc name

Tags: linux, bash, compare, tcl, proc

I have a requirement where I need to compare 2 tcl files, it will look something like below,

[Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXtRs.png)

Or here's the contents of file1 & file2.

```
File1:
========
this is content1 {
abc
efg xyz
}

this is content2 {
abc
efg xyz
123
}
```

And here's the other file.

```
File2:
========
this is content3 {
abc
efg xyz
123
}

this is content1 {
abc
xyz
}

this is content2 {
abc
efg xyz
}
```

So if you do the comparison using notepad++ or diff cmd, its not going to tell you what line is missing in which block.  Example the abc string inside of content1 of file1 gets checked against the content3 of file2. Which is not something I want. I want the content1 of file1 to get compared against content1 of file2. So i assume if i sort the proc with their names 1st and then do a compare, it would work. But how do sort the proc by names and case insensitive.

Comment: The hard bit — and _very_ specific to your use case — is the separating of the pieces into reorderable chunks.

Comment: I was thinking if we can collect all the proc names, sort it, and then display the entire block.

Comment: Your files don't have any procs? Maybe better example data more representative of the real stuff?

Comment: Can we go with awk to find the comment1 comment2 and then sort it, then print their set till ^}

Answer (score 0):

Well after doing some google, here's what I have come up with. I basically sorts and posts the content. But I'm losing the new line char. I tried \n too, no luck.

```
result=`cat file2 | grep "this is .* {" | awk '{print $3}' | sort`
for i in ${result}
do
output=`awk -v input="this is $i" '$0~input,/^}/' file2`
echo $output
done
```

And the output that i get is,

```
this is content1 { abc xyz }
this is content2 { abc efg xyz }
this is content3 { abc efg xyz 123 }
```

I want it as,

```
this is content1 {
abc
xyz
}
this is content2 {
abc
efg xyz
}
this is content3 {
abc
efg xyz
123
}
```